# .htaccess rules - Too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to accomplish 2 things with htaccess file:

1. Force https on all but 2 directories, only if accessed from prod url (no https on dev)
2. Redirect any nonexisting url in index.php

this is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect all http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myserver\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(api|images)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

When I add the first bit (the https enforce) I get "too many redirects" error. Any Idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RewriteCond` is only applicable to next `RewriteRule`. Your redirect rule for `http->https` is unconditional and will cause a redirect loop.

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect all http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myserver\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(?:api|images)[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part should look more like:

```
RewriteRule ^(api|images)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myserver\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```